# Changing the output inside a while True loop

Tags: python, string, while-loop

I am very new in Python and I decided to make a game.
I want a value to be output like this:

Heat: x #x would always be changing

For that I have the following block of code:

```
while True:
   print("Heat: {}".format(Heat))
```

but all it does is spam "Heat: xHeat: xHeat: x"
When it should be only one Heat bar
What should I do?

Comment: Then why are you putting this inside an infinite loop?

Comment: reset()
 print("Welcome to RM 1")
 print("Please choose a new difficulty")
 new=input("Enter a value between 1 and 3: ")
 setDifficulty(new)
 #Start
 clear()
 h="Heat: {}".format(Heat)
 #Loop
 while True:
  time.sleep(getDifficulty()/0.5)
  print(h)

Comment: @n0fares maroun has provided the answer

Comment: I want Heat to be always changing, thats why i put it inside an infinite loop. But my question is how to just put "Heat: " there without moving it anywhere, then adding its corresponding value which would be varying

Answer (score 0):

You can use carriage return to send the cursor to the start of the line.

```
import sys

while True:
    sys.stdout.write("\rHeat: {}".format(Heat))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

But this approach doesn't sound like you will be able to extend it into any sort of game.

You should look up the python [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/curses.html) library for complete control over the console output.

Also if the number of digits in your output changes then you might want to right-align the output so that you don't get any left-overs. This code demonstrates what happens if you go from a 2 digit number to a 1 digit number:

```
import sys
import time

for heat in reversed(range(5, 12)):
    time.sleep(0.5)

    sys.stdout.write("\rHeat: {:>5}".format(heat))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

In that code 'Heat' in the loop and it will be printed all the time:

```
Heat = 0
while True:
    Heat +=1
    print ('Heat: {heat}'.format(heat=Heat))
```

In that code 'Heat' out of the loop and it will be printed once:

```
Heat = 0
print ('Heat:')
while True:
    Heat +=1
    print ('{heat}'.format(heat=Heat))
```

if you want more newlines use '\n' char (strictly depends on OS).

Comment: I'll try that one out aswell. Thanks